# Firefox and Opera gives diferent elements when using elementFromPoint on area map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, area, mousemove

Sorry for not giving too much code. It's easy to understand.

I have a div wrapper and inside: one image and one map with areas.

I use `mousemove` on `div.wrapper`.

Inside `mousemove` I have the folowing js code:

```
console.log(
    $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)).prop('tagName') +
    ' - ' +
    $(e.target).prop('tagName')
);
```

Results from Opera (correct):

```
IMG - IMG
AREA - AREA
AREA - AREA
AREA - AREA
IMG - IMG
AREA - AREA
AREA - AREA
AREA - AREA
```

Results from Firefox (NOT correct):

```
IMG - IMG
IMG - AREA
IMG - AREA
IMG - AREA
IMG - IMG
IMG - AREA
IMG - AREA
IMG - AREA
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Note that you don't need to wrap a single element just to get a property like `tagName`. Access it directly as in `e.target.tagName`.

Comment: The discrepancy you've noticed is likely from implementation details. It works one way in one browser and a different way in another browser. Opera likely implements `<area>` as a rendered element whereas Firefox likely implements it as a modifier to how `<img>` works.